Further questions about correspondence theorem for rings and quotient ring isomorphism.
Background
This is a continuation of a post about correspondence theorem for rings, I will repost what I have written here from the Background section of that post here for ease of reference:
The ideal in a commutative ring $R$ generated by eleements $a_1,\dots, a_n$ is denoted by the wedge bracket notation:
$$\langle a_1,\dots, a_n \rangle$$
and sometiems the more informative noatation
$$Ra_1+Ra_2\dots +Ra_n.$$
Proposition 4.32 (Euclidean division with polynomials).  If $R$ is a commutative ring and $g$ is a non-zero polynomial in $R[X]$ such that its leading coefficient is a unit of $R$, then for eveyr $f$ in $R[X]$ there exist unique polynomials $q,r$ in $R[X]$ so that
$$f=gq+r\quad\text{and}\quad \text{deg }r<\text{deg }g\text{ or }r=0.$$
In particular, if $R$ is a field, then the above holds for all non-zero $g$.
Propositiion 4.49 (Correspondence theorem).: Let $\phi: R\to A$ be a surjective ring homomorphism. (Here $R,A$ need not be commutative.)  Let $\mathcal{J}$ be the family of ideals of $R$ containing $\text{ker }\phi$. and $\mathcal{L}$ the family of ideals of $A$.
(1) If $J \in\mathcal{J}$, then $\phi(J) \in\mathcal{L}$
(2) If $L \in\mathcal{L}$, then $\phi^{-1}(L) \in \mathcal{J}$
(3) If $J \in\mathcal{J}$, then $\phi^{-1}(\phi(J))=J.$
(4) If $ L\in\mathcal{L}$, then $\phi(\phi^{-1}(L))=L.$
(5) The mapping $\mathcal{J}\to \mathcal{L}$ defined by $J\mapsto \phi(J)$ is a bijection whose inverse is the mapping $\mathcal{L}\to \mathcal{J}$ defined by $L\mapsto \phi^{-1}(L)$
(6) If $J\in \mathcal{J}$, then $R/J\cong A/\phi(J) $
An Illustration of the Correspondence Theorem

The  isomorphism in item 6 of the correspondence theorem can be useful in detectin the nature of some quotient rings.  Here is a scenerario which could occur.
$\quad$ Say $R$ is a commutative ring and $a,b\in R$.  What can Proposition 4.49 reveal about the quotient ring $R/\langle a,b\rangle$?  Well, the canonical projection $\phi:  R\to R/\langle b\rangle$ is a surjective homomorphism, and its kernel is the principal ideal $\langle b\rangle$.  The ideal $\langle a,b \rangle$ contains $\langle b\rangle$.  By a simple verification the image $\phi(\langle a,b \rangle)$ is the ideal $\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle$ inside $R/\langle b\rangle$.  Since $\phi(b)=0$ the image $\phi(\langle a,b\rangle)$ is the principal ideal $\langle \phi(a)\rangle$.  According to the correspondence theorem
$$R/\langle a,b\rangle\cong (R/\langle b\rangle)/\langle a\rangle).$$
The right side is a succession of quotients of two principal ideals, which more readily be deciphered.
$\quad$ For example, let us describe the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^2+1,X-2 \rangle$.  Start with the substitution map $\phi:\Bbb{Z}[X]\to \Bbb{Z}$ given by $f\mapsto f(2).$  This is a surjection and its kernel is the ideal $\langle X-2\rangle$.  Indeed, $\langle X-2\rangle\subset \text{ker }\phi$ because $X-2$ has a root at $2$.  On the other hand $f\in \text{ker }\phi$.  Since $X-2$ is monic, Proposition 4.32 gives a polynomials $q,r$ in $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ such that $f=(X-2)q+r$ and $r$ is constant.  From $f(2)=0$ it follows that $r=0,$ and thus $f\in \langle X-2\rangle$.
$\quad$ The correspondence theorem gives a bijection between the ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ containing $\langle X-2\rangle$ and the ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$.  Now $\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle$ contains $\langle X-2\rangle$.  By item 6 of the correspondence theorem
$$\Bbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}/\phi(\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle).$$
In $\Bbb{Z}$ the ideal
$$\phi(\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle)=\langle \phi(X^2+1),\phi(X-2)\rangle=\langle 2^2+1,2-2\rangle=\langle 5\rangle$$
Thus
$$\Bbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle=\Bbb{Z}_5.$$
The original quotient is isomorphic to the finite field $\Bbb{Z}_5$.
$\quad$ Let us see what happens if we carry out the process in a different order.  Take the substitution map $\psi:\Bbb{Z}[X]\to\Bbb{Z}[i]$ given by $f\mapsto f(i)$.  This is a surjective homomorphism and its kernel is $\langle X^2+1 \rangle$.  Indeed, $\langle X^2+1 \rangle\in \text{ker }\psi$ because $i$ is a root of $X^2+1$.  On the other hand let $f\in \text{ker }\psi$.  Since $X^2+1$ is monic, Euclidean division gives polynomials $q,r$ in $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ such that $f=(X^2+1)q+r$ and $r$ is of the form $a+bX$ for some $a,b$ in $\Bbb{Z}$.  Since $f(2)=0$ we get $r(2)=a+bi=0.$ By the nature of complex numbers $a=b=0$, and thus $r=0$.  Having seen that $f=(X^2+1)q$ it follows that $\text{ker }\psi=\langle X^2+1 \rangle$.  By item 6 of the correspondence theorem
$$\Bbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}[i]/\psi(\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle) =\Bbb{Z}[i]/\langle \psi(X^2+1),\psi(X-2)\rangle=\Bbb{Z}[i]/\langle i-2\rangle.$$
Putting all of this together we come up with the less than obvious discovery that
$$\Bbb{Z}[i]/\langle i-2\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}_5.$$

Questions
I am stil having trouble with the following:  "By a simple verification the image $\phi(\langle a,b \rangle)$ is the ideal $\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle$ inside $R/\langle b\rangle$.  Since $\phi(b)=0$ the image $\phi(\langle a,b\rangle)$ is the principal ideal $\langle \phi(a)\rangle$," and how the author used $R/\langle a,b\rangle\cong (R/\langle b\rangle)/\langle a\rangle).$ to show $\Bbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle=\Bbb{Z}_5$?
For the first, I understand that $\phi(\langle a,b \rangle)=\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle$, but then to say that "....is the ideal $\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle$ inside $R/\langle b\rangle$, does it mean $\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle\subset R/\langle b\rangle$?  Also, how does $\phi(b)=0$ imply $\phi(\langle a,b\rangle)=\langle \phi(a)\rangle$?
As for the second, $\Bbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle=\Bbb{Z}_5$, how does their compuation connect to $R/\langle a,b\rangle\cong (R/\langle b\rangle)/\langle a\rangle)$, in the sense that $\Bbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle\cong (\Bbb{Z}[X]/\langle X-2\rangle)/\langle X^2 +1\rangle)$
Thank you in advance

If $\phi(b)=0$ then $\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle=\langle\phi(a),0\rangle=\langle\phi(a)\rangle$ (more generally, $\langle X\rangle=\langle X\cup{0}\rangle$ for any set $X$).

@NoahSchweber what do the authors mean by "...$\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle$ inside $R/\langle b\rangle$"?

Remember that the "$\langle ...\rangle$" notation depends on the "ambient ring" you're living in. So e.g. for $a,b\in R$, the notation $\langle a,b\rangle$ defines a subset of $R$ but since $\phi:R\rightarrow R/\langle b\rangle$ the notation $\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle$ defines a subset of $R/\langle b\rangle$. The author is just making this explicit. Subscripts might be clearer, e.g. $\langle a,b\rangle_R$ and $\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle_{R/\langle b\rangle}$ in this case.

As to the example, the intuition is just: modding out by $X-2$ identifies $X$ and $2$, and then further modding out by $X^2+1$ identifies $X^2+1$ and $0$ ... which is to say, identifies $2^2+1=5$ and $0$ since we've already identified $X$ and $2$. That's all that's going on.

@NoahSchweber when does this:  $R/\langle a,b\rangle\cong (R/\langle b\rangle)/\langle a\rangle).$ get used?  It seem like it is some theoretical interest.  Also, how is $\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle\subset R/\langle b\rangle$?

Re: your second question, do you understand that $\phi(a)$ and $\phi(b)$ are elements of $R/\langle b\rangle$ (rather than, say, $R$)?

@NoahSchweber no, i did not know the two are elements of $R/\langle b\rangle$, and how?

Look at the definition of $\phi$. It's a map $R\rightarrow R/\langle b\rangle$. So, $\phi(x)$ is in $R/\langle b\rangle$ for any $x$.

@NoahSchweber and hence $\phi(\langle a\rangle)$ is in $R/\langle b\rangle$ similarly for $\phi(\langle a, b\rangle)$

Yup, that's it.

@NoahSchweber thank you thank you.
